# Как поместить выезжающую панель в центре?

Tags: css

Всем привет!

Есть страница http://mn27.ru/test.html с боковой выезжающей панелью.
Как поместить выезжающую панель в центре экрана? Как сделать так, чтобы картинка также была по центру блока вконтакте?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно вот так:

```
<style>
    .panel {
        width: 300px;
        margin-top: -145px; /* высота панели деленная на 2 */
    }
    .handle
    {
        margin-top: 53px;  /* 145 - (высота кнопки деленная на 2) */
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('.panel').tabSlideOut({
            tabHandle: '.handle',
            pathToTabImage: 'vk_panel.png',     
            imageHeight: '184px',
            imageWidth: '36px', 
            tabLocation: 'right',   
            speed: 300,     
            action: 'click',
            topPos: '50%', /* Позиция сверху */
            fixedPosition: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Псмотреть можно здесь: http://jsfiddle.net/knsqN/1/.

Comment: Я обновил ответ, теперь кнопка тоже отцентрирована. Но мне кажется, что при выравнивании по верхней границе смотриться лучше.

Comment: я там даже в исходниках не вижу, чтобы Вы ее создавали

Comment: попробуйте ее поставить перед </body>

Comment: Поставил на страницу ОПТОМ перед закрывающим боди. И подскажите, как оставлять комментарий, не удаляя старый? А то у меня кнопка оставить комментарий пропадает.

Comment: И как эту проблему можно исправить? Или нельзя?

Comment: можно, у вас странице сначала грузится jquery 1.3, затем Ваш плагин, потом jquery 1.8, которая в свою очередь сбрасывает все функции добавленные через плагины. оставьте одну версию jquery и все будет работать. ну и смотрите чтобы порядок загрузки скриптов был корректным

Comment: СПАСИБО БОЛЬШОЕ!!!!!!!!!
Заработало :-) !!!